# Negative number test always fails

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm running some javascript using p5.js and I'm stuck with these two conditions :

```
if( this.colour >= 255 )
        this.up = false;
    else if( this.coulour < 0 ){
        console.log("Ca yest !");
        this.up = true;
    }
```

and here is my problem : the following line never evaluates to true, even if this.colour is negative

```
else if( this.colour < 0 )
```

Where is my error ? thanks alot

Comment: You have a typo in the `else if`. `coulour` instead of `colour`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo? `this.colour` is not same to `this.coulour`